# Keyboard navigation is not working with realPress() method in cypress

Tags: cypress, cypress-real-events

I am trying to mimic the keyboard navigation in my Cypress test. I found a nice lib https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#cyrealpress.

The method `realPress()` is working partially: not all key codes from https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events/blob/main/src/keyCodeDefinitions.ts are processing in my web application. Only `cy.realPress('Tab')` and `cy.realPress('Enter')` are working as expected - the cursor is focusing on the "next" element after `Tab` and the menu is opening after `Enter`.

But when I try to navigate as I am doing manually by keyboard (for example, using `cy.realPress('ArrowDown');` ) then the page is not scrolling. The same result is with other arguments:

1. `cy.realPress('ArrowUp');`
2. `cy.realPress('End');`
3. `cy.realPress('Home');`

Could you please give some advice on how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like no updates 5 months later on the GitHub bug report for this issue, either. https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events/issues/467

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Wonder if it has anything to do with keyboard layout. Since the keyset used in realpress is using the US-layout (see keycommands avalible) https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events/blob/main/src/keyCodeDefinitions.ts</strike>

I'm having the same issue and we are running cypress on a nordic layout where it seems end and home are on keycode 23 and 24. That does not map with the keycode defined in the list there which is 35 and 36 :/ been trying to find a way to switch layout but havent so far....

nvm! that was not an issue. Home and End works fine now with realPress('{home}'). Make sure you have the correct button or element focused when using it. In my case I was focusing another element that did not have the listener. Home and End is also a standard in cypress so you can skipp using realPress and just use. cy.type('{home}')

Example of my code:

Cypress:

```
      cy.get('button').contains('Tab-B').click();
      cy.get('button').contains('Tab-B').should('have.focus');
      cy.focused().type('{end}');
      cy.get('button').contains('Tab-C').should('have.focus');
      cy.focused().type('{home}');
      cy.get('button').contains('Tab-A').should('have.focus');
```

Template:

```
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
 <div role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <button type="button" role="tab" class="btn">Tab-A</button>
  <button type="button" role="tab" class="btn">Tab-B</button>
  <button type="button" role="tab" class="btn">Tab-C</button>
  <button type="button" role="tab" class="btn">Tab-D</button>
 </div>

<div class="tab-content" [hidden]="!active" role="tabpanel">
   <-show content dynamically depending on selected tab code not visible here->
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that **button** is not a typeable element.

Comment: do you have an element which is a button? My example above might not be fit to your html. Do you have an example of html/template you're trying to test?

Comment: added my template aswell to show which elements correspond to each cy.get